# cURL no longer working

Tags: php, curl

**Edit: I have now checked by using an HTML form to submit the data via POST and this works perfectly so is definitely a cURL error any help hugely appreciated! Seems strange this worked last night and now not tonight...**

o I managed to get my first cURL function working last night. For some reason (and with no changes that I'm aware of) it is not working today.

My code is:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.example.com/api");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "apiKey=var1&message=var2&to=var3&from=var4");

    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);

?>
```

Now I don't get any errors in the PHP log and I can't see any obvious syntax error. I've checked Im' using v7 and cURL is installed (if that's the correct technical term?). When I access the API address the POST data is going to without using this function it throws up an authentication error so at the very least I would expect this but only getting a blank page.

This leads me to believe the cURL itself is not POSTing the data but just ignoring it somehow. If I put headers in after the cURL they do follow this so their is definitely no fatal error in the code.

Comment: Does the authentication error have a HTTP status of `200`, perhaps? Have you tried turning on `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` and dumping out the return value of `curl_exec`?

Comment: What I mean is because I manually go to the page without using the apiKey variable it naturally gives me an authentication error. This error isn't being returned from the cURL so I know that's not the problem. The data itself just isn't sending. I must admit I would know how to turn on CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So it turns out my provider that has the API stopped accepting requests to HTTP and now needs to be HTTPS.

A quick fix to this - though I hasten to add not optimal from a security standpoint which is fine for us as the data is NOT sensitive but something to bear in my mind - is to add this line of code:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

At the beginning of your curl function.

I found the answer here which also discusses a much more robust fix:

http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: Any reason for downvote? This fixes the problem and provides the source. Would be nice to have an explanation especially for a new user

Comment: probably wrong, more likely, your provider stopped giving a default certificate bundle. so now you must give 1 yourself (see https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html ) or disable tls certificate authentication altogether. you chose the latter.

Comment: Thanks @hanshenrik appreciate the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not to point the obvious out but have you checked for curl errors?

```
$err = curl_errno($curl);
$errmsg = curl_error($curl);
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
```

Comment: Don't apologise I'm very new to this! Just tried this and echoed all the variables you provided and still blank

Comment: Ah sorry no actually I get this: "0array"

Comment: @Rockhopper don't use echo for debugging, use `var_dump`, echo can't differentiate between string(""), NULL, bool(false), these 3 are all the same to echo, also it cant differentiate between string("1"), int(1), and bool(true), they're all the same to echo... there's several other good reasons too.  **use var_dump for debugging.**